Align itemize items with the first item, in a theorem
I have an itemize environment inside of a theorem. The first item begins after the theorem's label, and the ones below it begin at the paragraph's left boundary.
How can I align the items start points, so they are all in line with the first one?
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}
\end{document}



\leavevmode is one of the better suggestion, i.e., \begin{proof}\leavevmode \begin{itemize}...

People usually looking for the following theorem style:

\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}~
    \begin{itemize}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{proof}
\end{document}

But as you like to have, it is not clear how the text in items should be aligned. As like is the following case?
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
\usepackage[base]{babel}    % for support of lipsum in LuaLaTeX
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{luatex85}    % <--- ADDED
\usepackage{linegoal}

\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linegoal}\raggedright
    \begin{itemize}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3  \lipsum[66]
    \end{itemize}
              \end{minipage}
\end{proof}
\end{document}


(red lines indicate page borders)
Edit
Problem of the se of linegoal˛ package at LuaLaTeX engine is solved by @mbert comment. Now the suggested solution works as desired.

Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. Please pardon my lack of insight.

linegoal seems to be designed for pfdtex, and I use luatex. Is there an alternative to linegoal that works for luatex?

@Jasper, package linegoal works with LuaLaTeX just fine.  Tested.

I get this warning when I run it on LuaLaTeX: Package linegoal Warning: This package requires pdfTeX for its \pdfsavepos primitive pdfTeX has not been detected and \linegoal will expand to \linewidth in any case on input line 34. Do you get the same warning? If so, does that mean it is benign?

@Jasper, yes, but this is just warning. However, you not make us aware that solution should work with LuaLaTeX˙. You can replace linegoal with linewidth and you will get desired result without this warning. See edited answer.

Thank you, my apologies for not adding that information - I didn't think it would be relevant at the time.

@Jasper, me either. Thank you for spotting this.

Sorry for taking so long to get back, but the minipage with \linewidth causes an overfull hbox: Overfull \hbox (42.51001pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--14. Sorry for all the nitpicks :-)

@Jasper, you are right. Now my code is corrected accordingly (width of \linegoal is now calculated manually).

Thank you for teaching me how to do this!

@Jasper, you are welcome! Hopefully one day code for linegoal will be extended for use in LuaLaTeX` too.

You can call \usepackage{luatex85} before loading linegoal

@mbert, thank very much for this info. I wasn't be aware for this possibilities. I must check linegoal package documentation, if this is mentioned in it.

It’s unlikely the linegoal doc will mention it. The package is for use with packages that assume pdftex
